# Component's indicator in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, spice

Maybe the chosen title is not proper but anyway:

What is "A" in the following LTspice code line? What is the pattern of the other specifications?

```
A1 uvl_ 0 N005 delaytest N009 0 Q 0 DFLOP trise=10n
```

Comment: Which SPICE are you using? LTSPICE? PSPICE? HSPICE? They all have slightly different syntax.

Comment: @The Photon, oops sorry, I didn't know that. this is LTspice. I updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In LTspice, the prefix `A` belongs to the "special functions" (see the help under *LTspice > Circuit Elements > A. Special Functions*). Among them are digital gates and counter, sample & hold, varistor, OTA, and a phase detector. For your case it's a digital D latch (named `dflop`), found in `[Digital]` (with the <kbd>F2</kbd> component browser). I'd recommend reading the help at least once, particularly since I see you're asking more than one question about LTspice, and it would only make sense to know the tool you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [spice tutorial](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/reference/chpt-7/fundamentals-spice-programming/) for more details.

A1 is a component in your circuit.

Comment: thanks, I've checked this website before but there is nothing about the "A" indicator. for example "R", "V", "C" refer to the resistor, voltage source, and capacitor respectively. but I couldn't find anything for "A".

Comment: @Kamran It's a `DFLOP` - it says so in the netlist line you provided.

Comment: @nanofarad, thanks, do you mean "A" indicates DELOP or can it be the indicator of any other component defined by designer?

Comment: @Kamran It's almost certainly generic and not specific to D-type flip flops (DFLOP, not DELOP)

Comment: In this case, the `dflop` is particular to LTspice (though Ngspice has some LTspice compatibility).